# Find which range a value is in and display name of the range

Tags: google-sheets

I want to check a value (name) against another sheet, which has names sorted into different groups, and have a cell display which group the name is in. For example:

If Smith, John is in range LIST1, then display "group 1". If its in range LIST2, then display "group 2" and so on.

Even "LIST1" and "LIST2" would work, I could just modify the range names.

Answer (score 1):

Q is IMO not clear. Assuming `LIST1` and `LIST2` are *named* ranges (so it does not matter they are on a different sheet) and that the value that may or may not be in one or other of the two named ranges is in A1 and that only two ranges are involved then perhaps:

```
=if(not(iserror(match(A1,LIST1,0))),"group 1",if(not(iserror(MATCH(A1,LIST2,0))),"group 2","n/A"))
```